# Cannot show UIAlertView with a text field

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

This piece of code which is supposed to show an alert window with a text input:

```
self.alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:@"How are you?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
self.alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[self.alert show];
```

Causes this error:

```
Thread 7: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"
```

This is how self.alert is defined:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    UIAlertView *alert;
    id <MyClassDelegate> __unsafe_unretained delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIAlertView *alert;
@property (unsafe_unretained) id <MyClassDelegate> delegate;
```

Comment: There's nothing jumping out at me (and you are using ARC, which should quash most memory management issues).  Can you show your UIAlertViewDelegate implementation?  Can you post a backtrace?

Comment: What version of iOS are trying to run this on?? The alertViewStyle is only available on iOS 5+. Attempting this on iOS 4.3 or below will crash.

Comment: Although on iOS4 it would probably be "unrecognized selector" for setAlertViewStyle. Is it on the UI thread?

Comment: Ah, good catch @SVD. I didn't notice the exception is on thread 7, which certainly at least raises the question of inappropriate UIKit use on a background thread.

Comment: @jmstone iOS 5, I am using Xcode 4.2 and Snow Leopard.

Comment: Sorry @RichardKnop but can you give me a feedback in my answer?

Comment: You should be using the strong attribute for ARC. The retain/strong differential is minor, but still. Is the crash on the self.alert show method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is maybe because of the customize.

I do not know why, but appear to me that the problem is because of the use of threads + customize of your alert.

Can you try to show this alert on the main thread? What happen?

You probably get an error in this line:
     self.alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

What you need to do if yes, is perform this in the main thread.

```
- (void) yourMethod{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(yourMethod2) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void) yourMethod2{
    self.alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:@"How are you?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    self.alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [self.alert show];
}
```

Sorry to can't help you more than that, but I do not know exactly what happen, but I already read about issues when editing things to show, in other threads.

Hope it help you!

Comment: I am too tired now. I will get back to you tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is caused by accessing a released object. To avoid this make your call to `UIAlertView` kind of modal:

Function body:

```
-(void)checkSaving
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
        initWithTitle:@"Do you want to add these results to your database?"
        message:@"\n\n"
        delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
        otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil];

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
    [alert show];

    //this prevent the ARC to clean up :
    NSRunLoop *rl = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    NSDate *d;
    d= (NSDate*)[d init];
    while ([alert isVisible]) 
    {
     [rl runUntilDate:d];

    }
}
```

Your choice result:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons

    if (buttonIndex == 1)//Save
    {
        //do something

    }
    if (buttonIndex == 0)//NO
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Register the functions in the interface declaration:

```
@interface yourViewController ()
    -(void)checkSaving
    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
//...
@end
```

To call:

```
[self checkSaving];
```

I wish this will help you.

Comment: Please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable.